# Determine $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $y=\csc(x)$ for $x(0,p)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $y=\csc(x)$ for $x(0,p)$.
Find the points where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists; and where $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$.

I obtained

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\csc(x)\cot(x)$$

Then I used limits to find where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists and I get $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

I am stuck as they asked for points. Also, I can't find where $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\csc(x)\cot(x)$ is $0$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$y'=-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\csc{x}=\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{\sin{x}}\right)$$

Use the chain rule with $u=\sin{x}$, so $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=\cos{x}$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=-1u^{-2} \cdot \cos{x}=-\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}}$$

It does not exist when the denominator equals 0:
$$\sin^2{x}=0$$
$$\sin{x}=0$$
$$x=0=\pi k$$

And it's 0 when the numerator is 0:
$$\cos{x}=0$$
$$x=\frac{\pi}{2}+n \pi$$

Where $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$